# Calling function to set array in server and printing array in client

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So I'm building the game battleship and I am using a 2d array for the board, but the problem is if I call the function to set the array, I have to call all other functions that use the array to get the same array, otherwise, it will just use a fresh new array. Right now I'm calling the setup function for the array inside the server, and when I call the function to print out the array to the GUI, it prints out a new array, any idea on how to fix this?

Server Class:

```
public class Server {
    private static PrintWriter writerSocket;
    private static BufferedReader buffedReader;
    public static String player1shipHit;
    Controller controller = Controller.returnController();
    private static String sharedMessage;
    int shipsLeftPlayer1 = 4;
    int shipsLeftPlayer2 = 4;
    public static String player2hit;
    private static InputStreamReader readerSocket;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    void waitForLock() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            try {
                lock.wait();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    void notifyLock() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Server().go();
    }

    void go() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5000);
        Socket connectionOne = server.accept();
        controller.player1.setUp(); //Setup
        System.out.println("Server>> P1 connected");
        writerSocket = new PrintWriter(connectionOne.getOutputStream());
        writerSocket.println("Player1> Enter your guess in the format: X,Y");
        writerSocket.flush();
        new Thread(new JobOne(connectionOne)).start();


        Socket connectionTwo = server.accept();
        System.out.println("server>> P2 connected");
        controller.player2.setUp();
        writerSocket = new PrintWriter(connectionTwo.getOutputStream());
        writerSocket.flush();
        new Thread(new JobTwo(connectionTwo)).start();

    }


    private class JobOne implements Runnable {
        Socket socket;

        JobOne(Socket name) {
            socket = name;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                readerSocket = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                buffedReader = new BufferedReader(readerSocket);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (true) {
                Controller.state = false;
                try {
                    sharedMessage = buffedReader.readLine();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String[] coordinates = sharedMessage.split(",");
                int x = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[1]);
                if (controller.player2.board.testHit(x, y)) {
                    controller.player1.board.updateBoard("Hit", x, y);
                    sharedMessage = "Player 2 has been hit!";
                    writerSocket.println(sharedMessage);
                    writerSocket.flush();
                    if (controller.player2.testShip("C", x, y)) {
                        sharedMessage = "Player 2's" + player1shipHit + " is Down";
                        shipsLeftPlayer2--;
                        if (shipsLeftPlayer2 == 0) {
                            sharedMessage = "Player 1 has won!";
                        }
                    }
                } else if (!controller.player2.board.testHit(x, y)) {
                    sharedMessage = "Player 1 misses!";
                }
                try {
                    writerSocket = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                notifyLock();
                writerSocket.println(sharedMessage);
                writerSocket.flush();
                waitForLock();

            }
        }
    }

    private class JobTwo implements Runnable {
        Socket socket;

        JobTwo(Socket name) {
            socket = name;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                writerSocket = new PrintWriter((socket.getOutputStream()));
                readerSocket = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                buffedReader = new BufferedReader(readerSocket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (true) {
                waitForLock();
                writerSocket.println(sharedMessage);
                writerSocket.flush();
                while (true) {
                    Controller.state1 = false;
                    writerSocket.println("Player2> Enter the coordinates in the format X,Y:");
                    writerSocket.flush();
                    try {
                        sharedMessage = buffedReader.readLine();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String[] coordinates = sharedMessage.split(",");
                    int x = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0]);
                    int y = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[1]);
                    ;
                    System.out.println("Player 2 X:" + x);
                    System.out.println("PLayer 2 Y:" + y);
                    Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(x, y);
                    if (controller.player1.board.testHit(x, y)) {
                        controller.player2.board.updateBoard("Hit", x, y);
                        sharedMessage = "Player 2 has a hit";
                        if (controller.player1.testShip(player2hit, x, y)) {
                            sharedMessage = "Player1s" + player2hit + "is down!" + 50;
                            shipsLeftPlayer1--;
                            if (shipsLeftPlayer1 == 0) {
                                sharedMessage = "PLayer 2 has won!";
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        controller.player2.board.updateBoard("Miss", x, y);
                        sharedMessage = "PLayer 2 has a miss.";
                    }
                    notifyLock();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Board class:

```
public class Board {
    public int[][] board1 = null;
    public int[][] board2;
    public Board() {
        board1 = new int[20][20];
        board2 = new int[20][20];
    }

    public void updateBoard(String type, int x, int y) {
        if (type.equals("hit")) {
            board2[x][y] = 1;
        } else if (type.equals("miss")) {
            board2[x][y] = '0';
        }
    }


    public boolean testHit(int x, int y) {
        if (board1[x][y] == 1) {
            board1[x][y] = 5;
            System.out.println("Its a hit!");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("It's a miss");
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Player Class:

```
public class Player {
    Destroyer destroyer;
    Battleship battleship;
    Submarine submarine;
    Board board;
    int[][] board1;
    Turn turn;
    int playerId;
    boolean guiState;
    Carrier carrier;
    ArrayList<String> ships = new ArrayList<String>(4);
    public Player(int playerIdSet){
            board1 = new int[20][20];
            playerId = playerIdSet;
            board = new Board();
            turn = new Turn();
            ships.add("Carrier");
            ships.add("Destroyer");
            ships.add("Battleship");
            ships.add("Submarine");

    }


    public void setSubmarine(Submarine subSet){
        submarine = subSet;
    }
    public Submarine getSubmarine(){
        return submarine;
    }

    public void setBattleship(Battleship battleshipSet) {
        battleship = battleshipSet;
    }

    public Battleship getBattleship() {
        return battleship;
    }

    public void setDestroyer(Destroyer destroyerSet) {
       destroyer = destroyerSet;

    }
    public void setCarrier(Carrier carrierSet){
        carrier = carrierSet;
    }

    public Carrier getCarrier(){
        return carrier;
    }

    public Destroyer getDestroyer() {
        return destroyer;
    }
    public Board getBoard(){
        return board;
    }

    public void setUp(){
        for (String ship : ships) {
            int x;
            int y;
            switch (ship) {
                case "Destroyer" -> {
                    x = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 0);
                    y = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 0);
                    if (board.board1[x][y] == 0) {
                        Destroyer destroyer = new Destroyer(x, y);
                         setDestroyer(destroyer);
                         getDestroyer().createShip(playerId);
                    } else {
                        x = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 0);
                        y = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 0);

                    }
                }
                case "Carrier" -> {
                    x = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 1);
                    y = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 1);
                    if (board.board1[x][y] == 0) {
                        Carrier carrier = new Carrier(x, y);
                        setCarrier(carrier);
                        getCarrier().createShip(playerId);
                    } else {
                        x = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 0);
                        y = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 0);

                    }
                }
                case "Battleship" -> {
                    x = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 0);
                    y = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 0);
                    if (board.board1[x][y] == 0) {
                        System.out.println("X:" + x);
                        System.out.println("Y:" + y);
                        Battleship battleship = new Battleship(x, y);
                        setBattleship(battleship);
                        getBattleship().createShip(playerId);
                    } else {
                        x = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 0);
                        y = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 0);
                    }
                }
                case "Submarine" -> {
                    x = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 0);
                    y = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 0);
                    if (board.board1[x][y] == 0) {
                        System.out.println("X:" + x);
                        System.out.println("Y:" + y);
                        Submarine submarine = new Submarine(x, y);
                        setSubmarine(submarine);
                        getSubmarine().createShip(playerId);
                    } else {
                        x = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 0);
                        y = (int) (Math.random() * (9) + 0);
                        System.out.println("Error checking...\n");
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void printBoard(){
        System.out.println("Attempting to print");
        for(int x = 0; x < board.board1.length; x++) {
            for (int y =0; y < board.board1[x].length; y++){
              System.out.println(board.board1[x][y]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayBoard(GUIController guiController) {
        StringBuilder grid = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder grid1 = new StringBuilder();
        for(int x = 0; x < board.board1.length; x++) {
            grid.append(x);
            for (int y =0; y < board.board1[x].length; y++){
                grid.append("[").append(board.board1[x][y]).append("]");
                grid.append(" ");
            }
            grid.append("\n");
        }
        guiController.gui.board1Area.setText(String.valueOf(grid));
        for(int i =0; i < board.board2.length; i++){
            for(int j =0; j < board.board2.length; j++){
                grid1.append("[").append(board.board2[i][j]).append("]");
                grid.append(" ");
            }
            grid1.append("\n");
        }
        guiController.gui.board2Area.setText(String.valueOf(grid1));

    }





    public boolean testShip(String ship,int row, int col){
        switch (ship){
            case "Battleship" -> {
                for (int[] ints : battleship.battleShipArray) {
                    for (int anInt : ints) {
                        return anInt == battleship.battleShipArray[row][col];
                    }
                }
            }
            case "Carrier" -> {
                for (int[] ints : carrier.carrierArray) {
                    for (int anInt : ints) {
                        return anInt == carrier.carrierArray[row][col];
                    }
                }
            }
            case "Submarine" -> {
                for (int[] ints : submarine.submarineArray) {
                    for (int anInt : ints) {
                        return anInt == submarine.submarineArray[row][col];
                    }
                }
            }
            case "Destroyer" -> {
                for (int[] ints : destroyer.destroyerArray) {
                    for (int anInt : ints) {
                        return anInt == destroyer.destroyerArray[row][col];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    void markShipHit(int x, int y){
        for(String ship : ships){
            switch(ship){
                /*case "Carrier" -> {
                    if(carrier.testHit(1,x,y)){
                        carrier.carrierArray[x][y] = 0;
                        Server.player1shipHit = "Carrier";

                    }
                }*/

                case "Battleship" -> {
                    if(battleship.testHit(1,x,y)){
                        battleship.battleShipArray[x][y] = 0;
                        Server.player1shipHit="Battleship";
                    }

                }
                case "Destroyer" ->{
                    if(destroyer.testHit(1,x,y)){
                        destroyer.destroyerArray[x][y] = 0;
                        Server.player1shipHit="Destroyer";
                    }
                }
                case "Submarine" ->{
                    if(submarine.testHit(1,x,y)){
                        submarine.submarineArray[x][y] = 0;
                        Server.player1shipHit="Submarine";
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Client example:

```
public class PlayerOne {
    Socket socket;
    InputStreamReader readerSocket;
    PrintWriter writerSocket;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    public static String input;
    GUIController guiController;
    boolean state = true;
    Controller controller = Controller.returnController();
    boolean setupState = false;

    public static void main(String[] args){
            new PlayerOne().go();
    }
    private void go(){
        guiController = new GUIController();
        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
            receiveRead();
            while(true) {
                if (Controller.state) {
                    writeSend();
                    Controller.state = false;
                } else {
                    receiveRead();
                    Controller.state = true;
                }
            }

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    void writeSend()throws IOException {
        while (input == null) {
            input = guiController.inputLine;
        }
        writerSocket = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        writerSocket.println(input);
        writerSocket.flush();
        controller.player1.displayBoard(guiController);
    }

    void receiveRead () throws IOException {
        readerSocket = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(readerSocket);
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        guiController.gui.setOutputText(line);
        controller.player1.displayBoard(guiController);

    }
}
```

Comment: So the board is generated (initialized with all the ships) on the server, right?
Any each client has an empty board, since they are separate processes (separate running JVMs). It looks like this is what you have. In other words I cannot see any code that transfers the board from server to client to have it displayed properly (neither code that updates it on the client side based on the server's responses). Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried using getters and setters, and even when I do that it still doesn't work.

Comment: OK, so it looks like you need to serialize and send it over the network (just like you send to [X,Y] shoot coordinates), receive it on the client side and reconstruct it once again on the client side.

The board is just 20x20 integers (400 total) so it should be possible to send all these integer one-by-one and receive them on the other side. I'm afraid that setters / getters does not work across separate processes.